# Django POST method for bulk creation using postman

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework, postman

I have POST method in **views.py** in django to create an entry in database
I can create a single entry using postman, but can not create bulk entries using postman
can anyone help, please?

**models.py** file

```
from django.db import models

class Users(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    function = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    logon = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user+" - Last_Logon: "+self.logon
    
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)
```

**serializers.py** file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from activities.models import Users

class UsersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Users
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'function', 'department', 'logon')
```

**views.py** file with GET,POST,PUT,DELETE, from this file POST method creates only a single entry

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http.response import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import status
from activities.models import Users
from activities.serializers import UsersSerializer
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def users_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = Users.objects.all()

        user = request.GET.get('user', None)
        if user is not None:
            users = users.filter(user__icontains=user)

        users_serializer = UsersSerializer(users, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(users_serializer.data, safe=False)
        # 'safe=False' for objects serialization

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        users_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        users_serializer = UsersSerializer(data=users_data)
        if users_serializer.is_valid():
            users_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(users_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JsonResponse(users_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def users_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        users = Users.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Users.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'The user does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        users_serializer = UsersSerializer(users)
        return JsonResponse(users_serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        users_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        users_serializer = UsersSerializer(users, data=users_data)
        if users_serializer.is_valid():
            users_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(users_serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(users_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        users.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'User was deleted successfully!'}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

**urls.py** file

```
from django.urls import re_path
from activities import views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^api/activities$', views.users_list),
    re_path(r'^api/activities/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.users_detail),
]
```

if I set many=True in user serializer, UsersSerializer(data=users_data, many=True) for POST metho

In postman, for sending a single entry, got this error
[image]

for sending multiple entries, got this error

[image]

Comment: can you share `user_data` with print in `users_data = JSONParser().parse(request)`

Comment: also to get `pk` inside the url, your function view must be `def users_list(request, pk):`

Comment: I have added the rest code in views.py

Comment: set many=True in user serializer, `UsersSerializer(data=users_data, many=True)` only for bulk

Comment: I have tried this befor, but it did not work
`elif request.method == 'POST':
        users_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        users_serializer = UsersSerializer(data=users_data, many=True)`

Comment: share a picture from postman

Comment: @Hossein Asadi, I have added the pictures above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246807/discussion-between-jonibek-and-hossein-asadi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `UsersSerializer(data=users_data, many=True)` you must send list of json objects

```
[
    {
        "User": "user1",
        "function": "t",
        "deportment": "t",
        "logon": "23...."
    }, 
    {
        "User": "user1",
        "function": "t",
        "deportment": "t",
        "logon": "23...."
    }
]
```

and for a user `UsersSerializer(data=users_data)`

you can split serializers with a send a query param into your url and in view function

```
if request.GET.get('bulk'):
    serializer = UsersSerializer(data=users_data, many=True)
else:
    serializer = UsersSerializer(data=users_data)
```

Comment: if so, it is giving this error
`500 Internal Server Error`